# 204 status code not working on Safari 11.1 with HTTP 2.0

Tags: macos, safari, http2

I have an API which returns 204, but ***safari Version 11.1*** on macbook is not able to parse it and results in request failure.

It works fine with http1.0 but NOT HTTP 2.0

Safari Network tab.
[image]

Notice the status & source in screenshot. I can provide more details if needed. As soon as I make it 200 it works fine. Is it something to do with http2.0 with safari 11.1 combination + 204 status code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a long standing bug with Safari:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60206

However I can same issue on HTTP/1.1 as HTTP/2 so are you sure it’s only HTTP/2? I tested using this site: http://httpstat.us

Comment: Yes. It is only HTTP/2. Because when I tested on my staging server which supports HTTP/1.0 it works fine.

Comment: Still seeing this in 2020. Though I think it might not be HTTP/2, but rather SSL (HTTPS) that is causing 204s to fail in Safari, as I am not seeing this bug in dev on HTTP 1.1/2, but am seeing it in stag/prod, which are both over HTTPS.